# How to combine two dataframes and have unique key column using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same columns that I need to combine:

```
  first_name last_name
0   Alex    Anderson
1   Amy     Ackerman
2   Allen   Ali
```

and

```
  first_name last_name
0    Billy  Bonder
1    Brian  Black
2    Bran   Balwner
```

When I do this:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df1, df1])
```

I get this:

```
   first_name last_name
0   Alex    Anderson
1   Amy     Ackerman
2   Allen   Ali
0   Billy   Bonder
1   Brian   Black
2   Bran    Balwner
```

Is there a way to have the left column have a unique number like this?

```
  first_name last_name
0   Alex    Anderson
1   Amy     Ackerman
2   Allen   Ali
3   Billy   Bonder
4   Brian   Black
5   Bran    Balwner
```

If not, how can I add a new key column with numbers from 1 to whatever the row count is?

Comment: use `pd.concat([df1, df1], ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier by @MaxU you can use `ignore_index=True`.

If you want to keep the index of your first table you can use the parameter `ignore_index=True` after the `[dataframe1, dataframe2]`.

You can check if the indexes are being repeated with the paremeter `verify_integrity=True` it will return a boolean (you never know when you'll have to check. 
But be careful because this procedure can be a little slow depending on the size of you Dataframe